# Acura TLX Vibrations in steering wheel and cabin

Tags: honda, noise, steering, vibration, acura

Information: 2016 TLX 2.4L Tech Package, purchased around November 2017 as a demo car with around ~7000KM on it. Currently has 13000KM on it.

The vibration is gentle throughout the cabin and most of the time you can feel it through your steering wheel and middle/top parts of the driver seat during idle or stopped at red lights. The vibration stops/lessens after putting in some gas to the car but comes back when fully stopped.

During startups, the vibration is the worst, and sometimes you can see the logo on the steering wheel shake, but calms down a bit after driving the vehicle for around 5mins. Every time passengers opens the doors, you can hear a rumbling sound throughout the cabin. The rumbling sound feels like opening windows where the bass is hurting my ears. The sound in the cabin is more vigorous when I open the passenger door and trunk together. I tried this in Park, Reverse, Neutral, and Drive but it still causes this problem.

I brought it back to the dealer a couple times and they said they couldn't find anything to fix, and told me to worry about nothing since its not causing damage. But the thing is, I didn't think Acura would produce this kind of quality cars. I even tested the vibration on my dad's 08 Kia Rondo and theres is some vibration coming from the steering wheel but not as bad as my 16 TLX. Could this be a transmission problem? I know that TLX has a transmission problem.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Has anyone (including the dealer) checked the motor mounts or any of the other mounts? Depending on your local laws, you may be able to take it back and/or exchange the car if they really can't find anything wrong. You may also want to talk to Acura directly. But I'd say wait for other answers as well because it could be something simple.

Comment: I live in Edmonton Alberta Canada, and I'll probably check around for the laws and I'm not sure what they did to my car when I gave it to them. They checked fluids and some other tests that they told me.

Comment: It might be worth getting the condition of the engine mounts checked

Comment: @caosdlke I'd say it's definitely making sure they checked the motor mounts and transmission mounts. As for anything dealing with returning or replacing, that's totally up to you. But as I mentioned, if the dealer is difficult, contact Acura. If you can get in touch with the right people, Acura will more than likely handle it for you. A family member had a similar thing happen with Ford here (US) and since other family work for Ford, he was able to contact the right person and Ford basically said "handle it or you don't sell Ford anymore!"

Comment: @kyle_engineer yeah I'll email Acura about this situation and bring this back to the dealership again and ask them to check my mounts!

Comment: @kyle_engineer I called Acura and asked about the exchange situation and they told me it wouldn't happen since they'll fix the problem no matter how long it takes

Comment: @caosdlke Figured. Same kind of thing happened with my wife’s door weatherstripping. It didn’t seal right and took a little work to get the dealer to handle it. I’d just keep at it with them.